# Find the functional dependencies that hold in a relation

Tags: database-design, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

There is a question in my book that asks the following:

> Suppose we have relation R(A,B,C,D,E), with some set of
> Functional Dependencies (FD's), and we wish to project those FD’s onto
> relation S(A,B,C). Give the FD’s that hold in S if the FD’s for R
> are:
>
> ```
> A->D
> BD->E
> AC->E
> DE->B
> ```
>
> In each case, it is sufficient to give a minimal basis for the full set of FD’s of S.

So I attempted to compute the closure of attributes for all of the subsets of (A,B,C).  I could not find any minimal basis of FD's for S.  I computed the closure of A, B, C, and AC, but I could not get all of the attributes.  A only implies AD, B only implies B, C only implies C and AC only implies ACE.  I could not find a functional dependency where there is a attribute on the left hand side that implies all of the attributes on the right hand side.

Comment: you mentioned that you cannot find any FD in which one attribute implies all others. I say there is no such an attribute and the minimal attribute set that can be used as a key is (A,B,C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see there is no attribute which imply A or C and also you cannot find any FD with A or C in left and B in right (A==>B or A==>C). So relation (A,B,C) has no FD other thant (A,B,C)==>(A,B,C).

Comment: Well the question itself is to find the minimal basis for the full set of FD's of S.  And from what I found was (A,B,C)-->(A,B,C) as well.  Can you confirm if this is the only possible FD for the minimal basis of S?  Cheers, and since you were only response I will be rating your answer as useful.